# "Choose among" vs. "choose from"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I am unsure on when to use *from* instead of *among* and vice versa.

Here is the question that I missed on an exam:

> The man had to choose [*_*_] 6 ties for the interview.

I chose *from* which apparently was wrong, even if,  to me, *from* sounds correct as well as *among* sounds correct.

I have tried to look this up on the Internet with no avail, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Was this a fill-in-the-blank question or a multiple-choice question? If it was a fill-in-the-blank question, the people who designed the question may not even have realized that "from" was a possibility, and were expecting you to choose between "between" and "among", and not among "between", "among", and "from".

Comment: *The man had to choose from among six ties* wouldn't be unusual either.

Comment: I agree with Choster. As a native speaker, my first thought was "from among," or "from amongst," and I wouldn't think anything of hearing just "from." However, "The man had to choose among six ties..." sounds off to me.

Comment: @chost, so "to chose from" is a phrasal verb there, and, so, "from" is its particle and "among" the preposition?

Comment: I don't get this question. For me the best choice would be *The man had to choose **from among** 6 ties for the interview.* Credible alternatives include ***between*** and ***out of***, as well as either of the "single word" options given by OP.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: To ***choose from*** isn't a "phrasal verb". It's just that the "selection pool" relevant to a specific usage of ***to choose*** can be optionally specified. And if it *is* specified, it's linked with a preposition such as *from*. Thus, *"I chose **from** the menu"* is valid. A direct object that can also be specified, as in *"I chose **lobster** from the menu"*, or just *"I chose **lobster**"*. But in no sense is there any kind of "phrasal verb" involved.

Comment: "From" - when the subject is separated from the group. Among - when the subject is still a part of the group.

The question was wrong, or a trick. "From" or "from among" would have been correct. Among implies the chosen tie isn't in the process of leaving the other ties behind.

Answer (score 5):

Both are valid, but they say very slightly different things. Carlo mentioned you can say "I chose from the menu" but note that you cannot say "*I chose among the menu" nor "*I chose from among the menu." I think that gives us the key to the difference.

When you say "chose [from] among" I assume you mean six physical ties. Now that you've taken one, only five are left. But when you say "chose from" I entertain the possibility that you mean six kinds of tie. That is, maybe you were shopping on Amazon, and there are still six ties for the next customer to consider.

This is a rule that runs at large. The difference between two expressions often cannot be seen without some context around them.

Answer (score 4):

With `choose from` you can select many items. With `choose among` you are selecting a single item.

If you're shopping and you `choose from` the items in a catalog, you can buy 17 items.

If you `choose among` the items in a catalog, you're selecting one item.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to choose among 30 different ties to find 3 different ties that matched my suit, why could I not choose among 30 to find 3?  Did the 3 not exist among the 30?

The meaning of from according to Miriam Webster:
1
a —used as a function word to indicate a starting point of a physical movement or a starting point in measuring or reckoning or in a statement of limits    
b —used as a function word to indicate the starting or focal point of an activity   
2
 —used as a function word to indicate physical separation or an act or condition of removal, abstention, exclusion, release, subtraction, or differentiation   
3
 —used as a function word to indicate the source, cause, agent, or basis

From only denotes a starting point, a removal/exclusion or source/cause/agent.

"I separated the good from the evil" is a correct usage of 'from' utilizing the second meaning.

The tie came **from** the closet.  The tie that I chose hung **among** six.  I kept the clean ties separate **from** the dirty ones.

In the statement "The man had to choose from six ties." We are declaring that "six ties" is the point of origin from where the tie was chosen without suggesting a variety to choose among.

In the statement "The man had to choose among six ties." We are declaring that he had six possible tie choices.

In the world that we live in today only a minority would catch that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you were being tested for the usage of between/among. Between relates to two objects, while among relates to three or more. The person who created the test probably did not consider "from" as a possibility, although it is still grammatically correct.

Comment: It is not true that *between* is limited to two. That's another of those dumb myths.

Comment: @tchrist Correct me if I'm wrong, but I've read that between usually applies to two things, while among applies to more than two things.

Comment: No doubt you've read it—just like you've probably also read that it's wrong to end a sentence in a preposition or split an infinitive from its 'to' marker. All commonly perpetuated misconceptions that have no basis in how the English language is actually used. Consider: “The meaning of 'jovial' is somewhere between 'hearty', 'friendly', 'forthcoming', and 'straightforward'.” Using 'among' would not work at all here; 'between' is the only real option. Similarly, “Between me, my brother, and my sister, we have five cats and four dogs.”

Comment: Okay, but I knew the other stuff you mentioned already ;)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Timtech's answer, I think what we're dealing with here is a badly written exam question, testing for a 'rule' of grammar that does not actually exist.

I would argue strongly that there is nothing wrong with saying

> The man had to choose from 6 ties for the interview
>
> The man had to choose between 6 ties for the interview
>
> The man had to choose among 6 ties for the interview

Only the most extremely pedantic English speakers would correct those sentences, even if used very formally.

I'd also argue that the following are just about acceptable, although they sound a little cumbersome to me.

> The man had to chose from among 6 ties for the interview
>
> The man had to chose from between 6 ties for the interview

Out of all the options written above, the one that feels most 'natural' to me is the one which the test probably intended to catch and mark as an error: "The man had to choose between 6 ties for the interview".

Answer (score 0):

I am not a native speaker but I suspect that 'choose from' is used in front of a singular while 'choose among' is used for a plural or a list of things.
eg: choose from the menu, choose from the selection
choose among the ties, choose among the dishes