# "choose from" vs "choose out of" vs "choose among"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I tried to form a sentence like this:

> X chooses Y from three Zs.
>
> X chooses Y out of three Zs.

I couldn't choose which one is better, and after googling found [question on en.se](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121437/choose-among-vs-choose-from)  and thread on [forum.wordreference.com](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2088643) and ended up with three options:

- choose from
- choose out of
- choose among

In the [question on en.se](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121437/choose-among-vs-choose-from) dcaswell's answer states:

> With `choose from` you can select many items. With `choose among` you are selecting a single item.

What about `choose out of`?
What is the difference between three options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preposition ***[from](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/out-of?q=out%20of)*** contains two meanings that might apply:

> 3. Indicating the source or provenance of someone or something:

or

> 7. Indicating separation or removal:

The preposition ***[among](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/among)*** contains a meaning that applies:

> 4. Indicating a division, choice, or differentiation involving three or
>      more participants:

The preposition ***[out of](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/out-of?q=out%20of)*** contains a meaning that combines *from* and *among*:

> 3. From among (a number):

All three expressions could correctly be interpreted with the same meaning:

> - *X chooses Y **from** three Zs* can mean *X chooses Y **from among** three Zs*.
> - *X chooses Y **out of** three Zs* can mean *X chooses Y **from among** three Zs.*
> - *X chooses Y **among** three Zs* can maean *X chooses Y **from among** three Zs*.

Still, each of the prepositions can also imply separate nuances according to their respective definitions.

The etymologies suggest different root ideas:

***[from](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=from&searchmode=none)*** suggests movement **to another location**:

> Old English fram "from, since, by, as a result," originally "forward
>   movement, advancement," evolving into sense of "movement away," from
>   Proto-Germanic *fra "forward, away from" (cognates: Old Saxon, Old
>   High German, Gothic fram "from, away," Old Norse fra "from," fram
>   "forward"), from PIE *pro-mo-, suffixed form of *pro (see pro-).

***[out of](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=of&searchmode=none)*** suggests movement **out** and **away**

> Old English of, unstressed form of æf (prep., adv.) "away, away from,"
>   from Proto-Germanic *af (cognates: Old Norse af, Old Frisian af, of
>   "of," Dutch af "off, down," German ab "off, from, down"), from PIE
>   *apo- "off, away" (see apo-). Primary sense in Old English still was "away," but shifted in Middle English with use of the word to
>   translate Latin de, ex, and especially Old French de, which had come
>   to be the substitute for the genitive case. "Of shares with another
>   word of the same length, as, the evil glory of being accessory to more
>   crimes against grammar than any other." [Fowler]

***[among](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=among&searchmode=none)*** suggests **connection to a group**:

> early 12c., from Old English onmang, from phrase on gemang "in a
>   crowd," from gemengan "to mingle" (see mingle). Collective prefix ge-
>   dropped 12c. leaving onmong, amang, among. Compare Old Saxon angimang
>   "among, amid;" Old Frisian mong "among."

The verb *choose* complements all three of those root meanings:

> - > What I choose moves ***toward*** me from the original group.
> - > What I choose also moves ***out*** and ***away*** from its original group.
> - > What I choose was ***part of the original group*** of choices.

[Dcaswell's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121437/choose-among-vs-choose-from) interpretation is legitimate: The preposition *among* tends to stand alone in its implication of exclusivity with reference to the original group, but that implication is not absolute in any way.